# Sum of Radio button values printed to the user

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm very new to html.

I have a survey with two questions where the question choices are presented with radio buttons as this html code shows:

```html
<form>
    <p id="description">1. Question 1?</p>
    <p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" /> No</label>
    </p>
    <p id="description">2. Question 2?</p>
    <p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> No</label>
    </p>
</form>
```

I want to print to the user the sum of his two selections.

So the output could be "You score is 10." if he answered yes to both questions etc.

How can I do this in the simplest way with the code being on the same page as the html code above?  Is that possible?

Comment: Use javascript to achieve. Also `id` of element should be unique on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var question1Answers = document.getElementsByName('q1');
var question2Answers = document.getElementsByName('q2');
var answer = 0;

question1Answers.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.checked) {
        answer += e.value;
        break;
    }
});

question2Answers.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.checked) {
        answer += e.value;
        break;
    }
});

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: This code make `var question2Answers = document.getElementsByName('q2');` to for many question the variable make ? can you edit the  answer for this hardcoding.. btw thanks :)

Comment: Update the answer for many questions are make the user.

Comment: I get a message on my console "SyntaxError: 'break' is only valid inside a switch or loop statement."

Comment: I think the solution by @dan-mullin is the most elegant.  There were some changes I had to make.  One was that break is not supported in a foreach.  So I removed the break.  It is not needed for my purposes, in the end it makes the code less efficient without the break but functionally its the same.  The second was change e.value to parseInt(e.value) otherwise I was getting a string concatenation of the numbers.  Otherwise, everything is working well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```js
$("input[type='button']").click(function () {
  var score = getChecklistItems();
  alert("You score is : " + score);
});

function getChecklistItems() {
  var total_score = 0
  var result = $("input:radio:checked").get();
  var checked_value = $.map(result, function (element) {
    return $(element).attr("value");
  });
  for (i = 0; i < checked_value.length; i++) {
    total_score += parseInt(checked_value[i])
  }
  return total_score
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p id="description">1. Question 1?</p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" /> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" /> No</label>
  </p>
  <p id="description">2. Question 2?</p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" /> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> No</label>
  </p>
  <p><input type="button" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```